# How to preview and download files more than 12 MB php?

Tags: php

I have a problem when click link for preview and download file with php script, but when that file less than 12 MB works.This is `download.php` code.

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0); // disable the time limit for this script
$filename='download/'.$_REQUEST['filename'];
if ($fd = fopen ($filename, "rb")) {
    $fsize = filesize($filename);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a file download
        break;
        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fgets($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }}
exit;
?>
```

And this is an error message :

```
Warning: fopen(download/22___006 TR - Copy - Copy - Copy (2).PDF): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\FMTmod2\download.php on line 5
```

FYI : Line 5

```
if ($fd = fopen ($filename, "rb")) {
```

Comment: what's your dl limit in .ini?

Comment: @treyBake, can you explain your question ?

Comment: though.. looking at the error, the size doesn't seem to have anything to do with it?

Comment: and it means the `memory_limit` option in the loaded .ini file :)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your **php.ini** to download/upload bigger file,

```
Upload_max_filesize  - 1500 M
Max_input_time  - 1000
Memory_limit    - 640M
Max_execution_time -  1800
Post_max_size - 2000 M
```

Or modify it in your **php** page with **init_set**

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '640M');
```